# Get minute part from time data type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

With the time data type (I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008), is there any way to take only the minute part out of it? I tried to pass the time to datepart and datediff function but both refused to work.

Example: I want to get 15 from 04:15

Comment: What do you mean, "refused to work"?  See my answer below.  Those examples give the desired output.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
select datepart(minute, '04:15')
```

Utilize the `DATEPART()` function, with `minute` as the datepart param.

```
declare @current_time time

select @current_time = getdate()

select datepart(minute, @current_time) as current_minute
```

[BOL Reference on DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

Comment: I strongly recommend the habit of specifying explicitly the datepart, e.g. `MINUTE` instead of `MI`. There are too many shorthand formats that are ambiguous to justify saving a few keystrokes. This very thing gets its own dedicated slide in my popular "Bad Habits to Kick" presentation. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Good point, and a great suggestion.  I've edited my post to reflect!